# jquery slideshow stop button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do everyone know how I can build a simple stop button in this code?
Is this with that code possible?

```
<div id="apDiv1">
  <ul id="exampleSlider">
    <li><img src="Images/A01.jpg" alt="" width="1049" height="768" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/A05.jpg" alt="" width="1049" height="768" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/A02.jpg" alt="" width="1049" height="768" /></li>
    <li><img src="Images/A03.jpg" alt="" width="1049" height="768" /></li>
    <li><img src="ImagesA04.jpg" alt="" width="1049" height="768" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    $(function () {

    /* SET PARAMETERS */
    var change_img_time     = 6000; 
    var transition_speed    = 600;

    var simple_slideshow    = $("#exampleSlider"),
        listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen             = listItems.length,
        i                   = 0,

        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });

        };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sample demo for you at the following URL using jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/ukNmT/

Please check that and modifications needed as per ur needs.

```
//To store timeout id
var timeoutId;

var slideImage = function( step ) {

    if ( step == undefined ) step = 1;

    //Clear timeout if any
    clearTimeout ( timeoutId );

    //Get current image's index
    var indx = $('.item:visible').index('.item');

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadeout this item
       $('.item:visible').fadeOut();
    }

    //Increment for next item
    indx = indx + step ;

    //Check bounds for next item
    if ( indx >= $('.item').length ) {
        indx = 0;
    } else if ( indx < 0 ) {
        indx = $('.item').length - 1;
    }

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadein next item
       $('.item:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();
    }

    //Set Itmeout
    timeoutId = setTimeout ( slideImage, 5000 );
};

//Start sliding
slideImage(0);

//When clicked on prev
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //slideImage with step = -1
    slideImage ( -1 );   
});

//When clicked on next
$('#next').click(function() {

     //slideImage with step = 1
     slideImage ( 1 );
});

//When clicked on Pause
$('#pause').click(function() {

   //Clear timeout
   clearTimeout ( timeoutId );    

    //Hide Pause and show Play
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//When clicked on Play
$('#play').click(function() {

   //Start slide image
   slideImage(0);

   //Hide Play and show Pause
   $(this).hide();
   $('#pause').show();    
});
```